# Print from another function

Tags: linux, bash, function, shell, variables

In order to save space on the codeline, I need to build a function to print out the info provided by another function, e.g:

```
# (1-1) Install APP
function installapp {
  echo "APP description goes here."
  echo "Installing..."
  xterm -e apt-get install app
  echo "APP Was Successfully Installed"
  echo "Run APP From The Menu"
  echo "Press Enter To Return To Menu"
  read input
}
```

What I would like to know is how I can turn it into something like this:

```
# (1-1) Install APP
function installapp {
  echo "APP description goes here."
  echo "Installing..."
  xterm -e apt-get install app
  echo -e "$done(APP)"
  read input
}
```

Where the `$done()` function has all the ending info quoted above.

Comment: Why on Earth do you run `apt-get` in `xterm`? Really, just don't.

Comment: It's not really clear what information you think is being passed and what you want to happen. Code which doesn't do what you want generally doesn't convey what you *do* want.

Comment: What is `$done()` and what does the dollar sign mean here? Do you have a variable named `done` which contains the name of a function you want to execute??

Comment: @tripleee it works 100% as it needs, no worries there.. Heheh

Comment: Well that's where I need help, I don't know if I need use a variable or a function for this. I want to print out the "INSTALLED" part appending the name of each app installed. So I don't have to be writing that part on every function, just adding and echo linking to another variable or function. Have no idea how to do it. I know that in command line I can just use "./app.sh hello world" returning $0 $1 $2, but inside the same script I have no idea.

Comment: I'm sure the `xterm` works but the drawbacks seem to massively outweigh any perceived benefits. That's why I'm asking why.

Comment: @tripleee My script has many apps to be installed while remaining on the same window, I use xterm so that the installation itself runs on a separate window leaving the main one clean with the only needed information. I didn't like to see the installation output on the main window in the middle of the information I really wanna see.

Comment: Using `xterm` for that is completely misdirected. `apt-get install -y app >/dev/null 2>&1` silences it without the portability problems, overhead, and annoyance of `xterm` (though I would perhaps save the output to a temporary file for debugging purposes, rateher than discard it entirely). Maybe replace your entire script with `apt-get install -y app1 app2 app3` though.

Comment: My first version was actually like that, but, I still wanna see the installation process, just not on the main window. But, I get your point, temporary file really caught my attention there. I may actually do it. Thank you very very much for your help.

Comment: The biggest problem I see is that you never confirm that the `app` really *is* installed correctly. `apt-get` could fail, and your function would ignore that and output `APP Was Successfully Installed`.

Comment: @chepner yeah that is another one of my issues, that's something I'm planning on fixing later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
installdone () {
    echo "$1 Was Successfully Installed"
    echo "Run $1 From The Menu"
    echo "Press Enter To Return To Menu"
}
installapp () {
      echo "APP description goes here."
      echo "Installing..."
      xterm -e apt-get install app
      installdone APP
      read input
 }
```

Notice the preference for POSIX-compatible function declarations (no `function` keyword, which is a rather useless Bashism) and the lack of a need to say `echo "$(installdone APP)"` when the function prints things just fine all by itself.

If this were my program, I'd also put `read input` in the `done` function (or probably omit it entirely; why would someone *want* that?) or perhaps refactor this more thoroughly to the point where the diagnostic chatter can be disabled entirely.

Comment: Ahm, just another thing, in case APP has more than one word, how do I do it ?

Comment: Thanks :) You saved my morning ;p Wish all the best